# Magento - Get children/options of an ORDERED bundle item

Tags: magento

I'm having difficulty getting all of the child products and their options of an ordered bundle item. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145980/how-do-i-get-the-options-for-bundled-products-on-the-success-page

Comment: That is for bundled options. I require access to the actual items that were bundled with a bundle product.

Comment: Have you tried $order->getAllItems() It should return all the products

Comment: Okay, that works well. However, the items don't seem to be linked to the bundle product in any way. It is just a list of every item ordered, without any bundled hierarchy.  Do you know of how I could find out what products are supposed to be attached to the bundle products in the list with all of the other items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you could find out what products are supposed to be attached to the bundle products in the list with all of the other items:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
     //if a product has parents (simple product of configurable/bundled/grouped product) load his Parent product type
     if ( $item->getParentItemId()) {
         $parent_product_type = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($item->getParentItemId())->getProductType();
          //if Parent product type is Bundle
          if ($parent_product_type == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
              // your code goes here (do whatever you need to do)
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Super helpful!! I'm going to try this out.